# Cache mapping calculation

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

A cache has following specifications:
Block size = 16 Bytes
Set size = 2 way set associative
Number of sets = 128
Physical address = 23 bits, byte addressable

**My Questions are:**
1) How many blocks **main memory** contains?
2) What is the extra memory required for cache?

According to me:
Total size of physical address = $2^{23}$ bits
Size of each block = 16 Bytes = $2^4 \times 2^3$ bits = $2^7$ bits
So total number of blocks = $$\frac{2^{23}}{2^7} = 2^{16}$$
But the answer in the book says it is $2^{19}$
As far as second question is concerned I don't know what does **extra memory** refers to.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I have updated the question.